# Sort multidimensional array based on another multidimensional array?

Tags: php, sorting

I have two arrays, say:

Array 1:

```
Array
(
    [test1] => Array
        (
            [abbrev] => Test data
            [title] => Test data
        )

    [test2] => Array
        (
            [abbrev] => Test data
            [title] => Test data
        )
    [test3] => Array
        (
            [abbrev] => Test data
            [title] => Test data
        )
)
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(
    [test1] => Array
        (
            [abbrev] => Test data
            [title] => Test data
        )
    [test3] => Array
        (
            [abbrev] => Test data
            [title] => Test data
        )
)
```

When array 1 was sorted against array 2, the result would be:

```
Array
(
    [test1] => Array
        (
            [abbrev] => Test data
            [title] => Test data
        )
    [test3] => Array
        (
            [abbrev] => Test data
            [title] => Test data
        )
    [test2] => Array
        (
            [abbrev] => Test data
            [title] => Test data
        )
)
```

So test1 and test3 are on top because they were sorted in the same order as in array 2, and test3 was put on bottom because it was not in array 2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
$arrayOne = array('test1'=>array(1, 2, 3),
     'test2'=>array(1, 2, 3),
     'test3'=>array(1, 2, 3),

);

$arraySecond = array('test1'=>array(1, 2, 3),
     'test'=>array(1, 2, 3),

);

foreach ($arraySecond as $key => $arrSecond){
    if (isset($arrayOne[$key])){
      $res[$key]= $arrSecond;
      unset ($arrayOne[$key]);
    }
 }

$res = array_merge($res, $arrayOne);
var_dump($res);
```

Result is:

```
 ["test1"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(3)
  }
  ["test3"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(3)
  }
  ["test2"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array1 = array(...); // array 1
$array2 = array(...); // array 2

$result = array_merge(array_intersect_key($array2, $array1), array_diff_key($array1, $array2));
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/07yl8v)

Comment: This also worked, but @sergio was a few minutes ahead of you.